# Fetching data in CodeIgniter - Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I saw the belove code in one software which builds in codeigniter

```
$this->view_data['customer'] = Customer::first(array('conditions'=>array('customer_id' => 311)));
$this->content_view = 'customer/customer_all';
```

above line fetches data from customer table which has customer_id = 311

now I Want to fetch data from quotation table which has quotation_id = 12
so I Wrote following code

```
$this->view_data['quotation'] = Quotation::first(array('conditions'=>array('quotation_id' => 12)));
 $this->content_view = 'quotation/quotation_all';
```

but this code is not working and showing error like this

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Quotation::first() in C:\wamp\www\pms\application\controllers\quota.php on line 26
```

Can any body help me saying that how this code is working

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Customer::first ? show full code of both

Comment: `first` function exist in `Quotation` class?

Comment: ok now check i write all full code of both controllers index function

Comment: No there is not any first function

Comment: `first()` is a UDF and not a framework function and hence you'll also need to define it inside your `Quotation` class before using it.

Comment: sorry but I don't know what is UDF and here in this customer controller it's working fine but not in this quotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you're referencing would have a structure something like this:

```
class Customer{
   .
   .
   .
   public static function first($where){
   ....
   }

}
```

OR

```
class Customer extends SomeOtherClass{
    // the function first() might be present in the SomeOtherClass class.
}
```

where as your class `Quotation` is missing this function. Hence the error is being displayed telling you that it tried to look for a function `first()` inside your class `Quotation`, but did not find it.

EDIT: As per your comment, yes you're right. The `Customer` class must be extending another class which contains the public function `first()`. That would be the only explanation for not finding `first()` inside the `Customer` class.

<kbd>[**Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oPVi7w)</kbd>

Comment: no there is no such method in customer class so is there anywhere else like in parent::__construct(); that function first(); written

Comment: Ya i am finding it in my software but can you suggest me where can i find for it

Comment: Inside the `Customer` class see if there are any files included. Or search for the filename which matches the name after the `extends` keyword. For example: `class Customer extends Abc`, then search for `Abc.php` file

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `first()` function inside `Quotation` class then that is why you get this error. You are trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ya but there is no first function in customer then also it is working fine so can you tell me any other way or page to save & call function in CodeIgniter

Comment: The error message is pretty obvious. You are trying to call a method that is not defined. Please post all your code from classes Customer and Quotation and then we maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined in Customer Class but not in Quotation Class.
try to define it in Quotation Class.